Model breaks on FBX import
I'm having an issue trying to import a simple rigged hand model (made with 3DS Max few years ago).
The model shows correctly when i open it with a 3D viewer like Autodesk FBX Review, the animation and the rig seem perfectly fine.
But when i import it with Blender, the bones and the hands are completely messed up on the position, rotation and even scale.

I already got this issue with previously made FBX on 3DS Max when a hierarchy is implied, even without any kind of rigging/skinning.
I don't have access to 3DS Max anymore but i need to use this model.
Is there any import options i'm missing to get a proper import ?
Thanks.

Well after some search i found about this addon "Better Fbx Importer & Exporter" (28$ USD) that solves the issue. Too bad blender isn't able to do it natively, or at least for free. Cheers.

After importing FBX try this:

Select the armature and switch to Pose Mode
Press A to select all bones
Pose > Clear Transform > All

